# Get plain text from html but want to keep title attribute in select tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to parse html tags and want to remove  from code (not title) which is given in TextArea1 and want to show output in TextArea2 on button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br />       //for input
    <textarea id="TextArea2" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br />       //for output
    <input id="Submit1" onclick="parsehtml()" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <script>
        function parsehtml()
        {
            var div = document.createElement("div"); //created a div
            div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('TextArea1').value; //copied the source text as HTML into the div
            for (let select of div.querySelectorAll("select")) select.remove(); //Lopped select tags inside the div and removed them
            document.getElementById('TextArea2').value = div.innerText.replace("  ", " "); //Copied the result into the target
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my TextArea1 i have code like

```
Hello 
<select>
<option>Opttion1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
</select>
World 
<select title="Welcome">
<option>Opttion11</option>
<option>Option22</option>
</select>
```

This code return output like:

```
Hello 

World
```

Please help me to remove all `<select>...</select>` with all of it's `<option>` and **innerText** but want to keep title attributes value want to output like this:

```
Hello 
World 
Welcome                 //title of <select title=""> tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [document.createNodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator)  to parse and output what you want

```js
function parsehtml() {
    let root = document.createElement("div");
    root.innerHTML = document.getElementById("TextArea1").value;
    let node;

    let output = "";
    let nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL);
    while ((node = nodeIterator.nextNode())) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.parentNode.tagName !== 'OPTION') {
            output += node.textContent;
        } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (node.hasAttribute("title")) {
                output += node.getAttribute("title");
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("TextArea2").value = output;
}
document.getElementById("Submit1").onclick = parsehtml;
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="10" cols="100">
          Hello 
          <select>
          <option>Opttion1</option>
          <option>Option2</option>
          </select>
          World 
          <select title="Welcome">
          <option>Opttion11</option>
          <option>Option22</option>
          </select>
        </textarea><br />       //for input
        <textarea id="TextArea2" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br />       //for output
        <input id="Submit1"  type="submit" value="submit" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Your code return <option> innerText, but i want to remove <option></option> innerText. As mentioned in my output. i want to keep only title attributes value such as <select title="This is title"><option>Opt1</option><option>Opt2</option></select>. and want output like: **This is title**

Comment: in that case you can add one more condition `node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.parentNode.tagName!=='OPTION'`